# How to find Maximum and Minimum in an array of Int,float and String in Java

Tags: java

Is there a way to find out the Maximum and minimum of an array consisting of integer, floating point number and string or characters? in java

for example:
A={1,2,3,4,4.5,4.4,NA,NA,NA}

so Ignore all the characters and strings

expected outcome:
Maximum element here is 4.5
and the minimum is 1

Comment: How does `"NA"` compare to `1`?

Comment: no, if you observe carefully, the array has '1'

Comment: The question was about your comparison logic, be that `1`, `'1'`, or `"1"`...

Comment: Just do a regular loop and only keep track of numbers.

Comment: ok, in the given array it should ignore the characters or strings and just search for max and min across integers and floating points

Comment: One important question is how you ended up with an array like this. It indicates bad design. Java is a type-checked language for a reason. Mixing things in the same data structure and then trying to unmix them is not a good design.

Comment: they are coming from DB as strings for requested entry

Comment: So you are using an array with the type Object?

Comment: So when you get them from db, don't put them in the array if they are not numbers. And I still suspect that this is bad design, because the semantics of that column in the DB seems to be too loose.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should hopefully get the job done. I've only considered int, double and strings.

```
    ArrayList<Object> list = new ArrayList<Object>(Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3, 4, 4.5, 4.4, "NA", "NA", "NA"));
    double num , max  = Float.MIN_VALUE;
    for (Object item : list)
    {
        if (item instanceof Integer)
        {
            num  =(int)item + 0.0;
        }
        else
        {
            if(item instanceof String)
            {
                // don't do anything - skip 
                continue ;
            }
            else
            {
                // is a double
                num = (double)(item) ;

            }
        }
        if(num >= max)
        {
            max = num ;
        }
    }
    System.out.println(max);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how I would do this with Java 8+

```
Object[] array = new Object[] { 1, "2", 2.5f, 3, "test" };
double result = Stream.of(array)
                    .filter(x -> x instanceof Number)
                    .mapToDouble(x -> ((Number) x).doubleValue())
                    .max().orElse(Double.MIN_VALUE);
```

-> result=3

Comment: Beware that converting from a float (if any) to a double means losing precision.

Answer (score 0):

You can extract the `float` and `int` out of your array neglecting `string` values and then find maximum and minimum values.

```
import java.util.Arrays;
public class stackMax
{
    public static void main (String[] args)
    {
        String[] A={"1","2","3","4","4.5","4.4","NA","NA","NA"};
        System.out.println(findMax(A));
    }

public static String findMax(String[] A)
{
    int max=0,min=0; //stores minimum and maximum values
    int f=0;  //counter to store values in "float" arrays
    //store length for FloatArray so we dont get extra zereos at the end
    int floatLength =0;

    for(int i=0;i<A.length;i++){
        try{
            Float.parseFloat(A[i]);
            floatLength++;
        }
        catch(NumberFormatException e) {}
    }

    //arrays to store int and float values from main Array "A"
    float[] floatArray = new float[floatLength];
    for(int i=0;i<floatLength;i++){
        try{ //checking valid float using parseInt() method 
            floatArray[f] = Float.parseFloat(A[i]); 
            f++;
        }  
        catch (NumberFormatException e) {}      
    }
    Arrays.sort(floatArray);
    return String.format("\nMaximum value is %.1f\nMinimum value is %.1f",floatArray[floatArray.length-1],floatArray[0]);
}       
}
```