# Find an object with biggest semver version

Tags: spring, mongodb, spring-data, criteria, spring-data-mongodb

Let's say I have some documents in MongoDB with a `version` property(semver version), for example something like `{ ..., version: { major: 1, minor: 2, patch: 13 } }`, or `{ ..., version: "1.2.13" }`, i haven't decided yet which format i will be using.

I need to find the document with the highest `version`.
For example, if collection has two documents with `{..., version: "0.10.0"}` and `{..., version: "1.0.0"}` then i would like to get document with `version = "1.0.0"`

I'm using Spring Data MongoDB, so ideally i would like to find some solution by using `Criteria API`

Comment: Are you facing difficulties with mongo query or spring mongo code?

Comment: Parse the highest version using this - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55127398/how-to-find-maximum-and-minimum-in-an-array-of-int-float-and-string-in-java

Comment: @AjayKumar i would like to do that on database side, not in java code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It turned out to be quite simple when i use first format of `version`:
`{ ..., version: { major: 1, minor: 2, patch: 13 } }`

Then i can just sort by all those three fields and take the one top document:

```
db.metadata.find({})
   .projection({})
   .sort({ "version.major": -1, "version.minor": -1, "version.patch": -1 })
   .limit(1)
```

This query is written by using `Criteria API`:

```
public Metadata getLatestMetadata() {
    Criteria criteria = Criteria
            .where("type").is(TEST_TYPE);

    Query query = Query.query(criteria).with(getVersionSort()).limit(1);
    return mongoOperations.findOne(query, Metadata.class);
}

private Sort getVersionSort() {
    return Sort.by(new Sort.Order(Sort.Direction.DESC, "version.major"),
            new Sort.Order(Sort.Direction.DESC, "version.minor"),
            new Sort.Order(Sort.Direction.DESC, "version.patch"));
}
```